# Difference between event child_added of Realtime Database Firebase vs Firebase Cloud function

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I having a case where I need to receive notification whenever Realtime Database Firebase have new data. When investigate, I found out there are 2 way to do this in client side (mobile app using React Native):

- Using [Realtime Database child_added event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added)
- Using [Cloud Functions event onWrite()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Can someone please tell me what is the difference between 2 way and pros and cons of each way?. The document is not helpful for me about this.

Note:

- Backend Server written in Java framework Spring boot response function push new data to Realtime Database Firebase.
- Client side need to receive notification when new data added to Realtime Database Firebase (currently only mobile app written in React Native but I also need to do it for web in the future)

Comment: You've linked the Admin SDK and Android implementation of the `child-added` event. There is no significant difference between `child-added` on various platforms. --- As it stands your question it unclear and will likely be closed. I recommend editing it (there's a link under it), to describe what you are trying to accomplish (and on what platform).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you, you are right, I had mislead the link. Please check it again to see if it cleary enough.

Comment: You are now comparing two completely separate databases: Firestore and Realtime Database. While both are part of Firebase, that's pretty much where the overlap ends. If you want to trigger a Cloud Function from Realtime Database, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: @Dattq2303 can you please let us know if the above comment helps you?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty yes it does. I'm trying both way now

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrasing [Frank Van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70848186/difference-between-event-child-added-of-realtime-database-firebase-vs-firebase-c/71351328#comment125258001_70848186) as an answer:

Firestore and Realtime databases are two completely separate databases. Though firestore and Realtime database both are part of Firebase. If you want to trigger a cloud function from Real Time database, please follow [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events). If you want to trigger cloud function from Firestore, please [check this documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore)